# Simple shell script to backup to Amazon over iSCSI

Tags: linux, shell, network-file-transfer, amazon-web-services

The script works but I know that it can be improved. Please note that my scripting skills are very basic :) (as it can be seen in my Frankenstein script – I took bits and pieces of the code from different tutorials).

I would appreciated if someone could review this script and identify some major flaws.

Some other questions that I have:

1. After the backup is complete is it necessary/better to logout from the amazon and unmount the volume?
2. Is it better to check if the volume is mounted based on the UUID?

```
#!/bin/bash
##
## VARIABLES
##
BACKUP_FROM="/folder/"
BACKUP_TO="/folder/"
LOG_FILE="/var/log/backup.log"
SCSI="/sbin/iscsiadm"
VOL="ghrryhfd-56655565-456456-3453-dfhthjtrrgg"
##
## SCRIPT
##
# Check that the log file exists
if [ ! -e "$LOG_FILE" ]; then
    touch "$LOG_FILE"
fi

# Check if the volume is mounted if not login to amazon and mount
if mountpoint -q /mount_folder; then
echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Volume mounted" >> "$LOG_FILE"
else
echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Mounting!" >> "$LOG_FILE"
$SCSI --mode node --targetname abc.222-99.com.amazon:volume_name --portal 1.1.1.1:9999 --login
sleep 10
mount -U "$VOL" /mount_folder
sleep 8
fi

# Start entry in the log
echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Sync started." >> "$LOG_FILE"

# Start sync
if rsync -a -v "$BACKUP_FROM" "$BACKUP_TO" &>> "$LOG_FILE"; then
    echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Sync completed succesfully." >> "$LOG_FILE"
else
    echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - ERROR: rsync-command failed." >> "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - ERROR: Unable to sync." >> "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    exit 1
fi

# End entry in the log
echo "" >> "$LOG_FILE"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Extract common logic to a helper function

Notice the similarity in these statements:

> ```
> echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Volume mounted" >> "$LOG_FILE"
> ...
> echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Mounting!" >> "$LOG_FILE"
> ...
> echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - Sync started." >> "$LOG_FILE"
> ```

They all have the same pattern:

```
echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - MESSAGE" >> "$LOG_FILE"
```

So it's a good candidate to turn into a function:

```
log() {
    echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S") - $@" >> "$LOG_FILE"
}
```

So that you can simplify the uses like this:

```
log "Volume mounted"
...
log "Mounting!"
...
log "Sync started."
```

#### Result of `mount`

The `mount` command might fail. When that happens, you might want to abort:

```
if ! mount -U "$VOL" /mount_folder; then
    log "Unable to Mount"
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Pointless `touch`

This code is completely unnecessary. 
Whether the file existed or not, whether you `touch` it or not,
it won't affect the rest of the script.
You can safely remove it.

> ```
> if [ ! -e "$LOG_FILE" ]; then
>     touch "$LOG_FILE"
> fi
> ```

#### Simplify

This is kind of tedious:

> ```
> echo "" >> "$LOG_FILE"
> ```

You can just drop the `""` to simplify:

```
echo >> "$LOG_FILE"
```

And, you don't need `exit 0` at the end of the script.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to look over my code. I made those changes you suggested and the code looks much better and works very well! I am thinking of adding additional if statement to stop the script if the mount fails. Can I do something like that: 
   ...
    sleep 10
    mount -U "$VOL" /mount_folder
    if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
     log "Unable to Mount"
     exit 1;
    fi
    sleep 8
    fi
    ...

Comment: @Pete good thinking! Actually I should have pointed that out for you myself... I added a section for it now, good catch!